# iphone tabbar pop or back to main view problem

Tags: iphone, ios4

1.

```
  When app. launch it's display loading screen.
```

2.

```
  After loading screen have another screen that contain 4 button.
```

3.

```
  If i select any button that after next screen No.3  contain tabbar controller.

  So now i want to pop (or back to second)screen. but due to the tabbar controller on 3rd screen i can't go to back on second screen that the problem i faced now.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put one ToolBar or NavigationBar on top in 3rd screen and put one button in that to go back to 2nd ViewController.
Best of luck.

Comment: i know that about back button but due to the tabbar controller i can't go back to main view.